# Using SQL in R turns Queried Field into a Boolean Value

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I'm running into a weird issue with R; I'm running a very simple SQL script and when I execute the query, one field returns TRUE/FALSE --- Boolean values instead of its actual, stored, values.

I played around with my query and noticed the issue occurs because I'm filtering my dataset based on the field returning the TRUE/FALSE. I removed the filter and this field returned its true values which can be either a numeric, alphabetic or Null value.

This seems to be an issue on R's side (maybe with how it is communicating with SQL Server) but I'm not sure what is really going on, does anyone have an idea of why this is happening and if its possible to resolve the issue?

An example of the data  BEFORE the filter looks like this:

| ID | FrequencyCode |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | 4 |
| 482937 | 3 |
| 869833 | NULL |
| 104932 | F |

An example of the data AFTER I filter the dataset to include rows where FrequencyCode = F ... (F doesnt stand for FALSE)

| ID | FrequencyCode |
| --- | --- |
| 104932 | FALSE |
| 720740 | FALSE |
| 174934 | FALSE |
| 567393 | FALSE |

My code:

```
SELECT 
AccountNumber,
DateProcessed,
OrderNumber,
FrequencyCode
FROM 
tablexyz
WHERE
FrequencyCode = 'F'
```

Comment: It seems like your code is interpreting `FrequencyCode = F` as assigning `FALSE` to `FrequencyCode`. Hard to know what's going wrong without seeing any of your code... normally strings have quotes around them, which helps to differentiate the string `'F'` from the boolean value `F`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited to add my code. I do use the quotes around the filtered character.

Comment: Since you think the comment is on the R side, could you perhaps add some of the R code? Are you running the query from within R? If so, what package are you using and what function?

Comment: I can run `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select 123456 as ID, 'F' as FrequencyCode")` and the second column is `character`, so I don't know where the issue is, sorry.

Comment: *However*, `read.table` and such often use `type.convert`, which will interpret `F` in a column as a `logical` indicator, not a string. Since I've tested with `DBI-1.1.1` and `odbc-1.3.1` and cannot reproduce it on the ODBC side, perhaps you are doing something more than just `DBI::dbGetQuery`?

Comment: To help narrow this down, please show the R code making the query, as well as the output from `sessionInfo()` and, perhaps even more telling, the output from `subset(odbc::odbcListDrivers(), grepl("sql ?server", name, ignore.case = TRUE))` and `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select @@version")`, something there may give a clue. (In addition to R's `DBI` and `odbc`, the other two components can just as easily play a part in this.)